# How do I change gamma on wayland

Tags: configuration, wayland, gamma

On X, I could change gamma by tuning the xorg.conf file and add a "Gamma" line with the right value to the "Monitor Section".
How do I do this on wayland?
[edit]Or: What's the name of the tool for doing this in wayland and how can I make that config persistent?·[/edit]

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do it?

Comment: No. Still, no clue for this.

Comment: Guess it's only doable with icc-profiles in f.e. the GNOME-preferences (Devices-Colors).

Comment: Still no means in Wayland to adjust gamma?

Comment: The Python script in this repo seems to do the trick. [https://github.com/zb3/gnome-gamma-tool] It had some dependencies I needed to install with apt and pip, but it's working for me. Just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and still fighting to get apps to go fullscreen...

Answer (score 0):

Try `ddcutil` to set it.

```
$ sudo su
# apt install ddcutil
# ddcutil getvcp color
```

When I run this, I get this control for Gamma:

```
VCP code 0x72 (Gamma                         ): 0x0000 - Mode: White absolute adjustment (sl=0x00), gamma=1.00 (sh=0x00)
```

But I think every monitor is different. My Dell 24" doesn't seem to allow changing that entry, but it does allow me to set brightness, e.g, with `ddcutil setvcp ...`

So your mileage may vary, but it is worth it to try.

Also, I haven't figured out yet if gamma is something your set for monitor, or for graphics card? If you are on nvidia, you could also try the `nvidia-settting` tool.